# Why Is The Substring Function Not Working?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, substring

I am getting an error message for a program that normally works, code below:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('url.com');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));
  
  var date = new Date();
  Logger.log(date);                                 //Sat Aug 22 17:28:54 GMT+01:00 2020
  var day = date.getDate(); 
  Logger.log(day);                                  //22
  
  for (var i = 2; i < 1400; i++) {
    var gamedandt = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    Logger.log(gamedandt);                          //Sat Aug 22 14:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020
    /*Line 47*/ var gameday = gamedandt.substring(9, 2);
  }

}
```

The error message I receive says:

> TypeError: gamedandt.substring is not a function (line 47, file "myFile")

I believe the problem to be the data I want substringed - it is a date.
The script worked fine in the past but the data would simply have the date and time (eg. '22 14:00') rather than the now full date which includes month, year, weekday, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getValue()` / `getValues()` you could use `getDisplayValue()` / `getDisplayValues()` to get strings instead of (JavaScript data types) `Date`, `Boolean`, `Number` values when the cell contains values of type (Google Sheets / spreadsheets data types) `DATE`, `TIME`, `DATE TIME`, `DURATION`, `NUMBER`, `BOOLEAN`, etc.

Related

- [Random substring error? "TypeError: Cannot find function substring in object..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35256409/1595451)
- [Identify specific row based on Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63314549/1595451)

Comment: Words do not describe how I feel after finding this out. I have been using Google Apps Scirpt for years and I am only just finding out about this!? This getDisplayValue() is going right into my toolkit. Grazie mille Rubén, I hope you have a great night tonight - it is deserved.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` does not have a `substring` method. It is possible  to convert `Date` to a string using

- one of the [`Date` instance methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Instance_methods): `.toString()`,`.toLocaleString()`,`.toLocaleDateString()`
- or directly get the displayed string using [`getDisplayValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) instead of `getValue()`
- To `getDate()` from `Date`,

  ```
  var gameday = gamedandt.getDate();//22
  ```

Comment: So how would I pull the '22', which is the day, from the 'gamedandt' variable (data stored in this is 'Sat Aug 22 14:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020')?

Comment: @Michael See the first link. Let me know  which of those methods seem more likely to pull the day of the month

Comment: @Michael Huh. Wasn't my second link getDisplayValue()?